# PayPal Adaptive Payments Authentication failed, Inputs are Name value pair. In java

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am getting Authentication failed from the paypal sand box, I am sending the request to the pay pal as a name value pair..

Code is below:`

```
final String PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE="UTF-8";
final StringBuffer encodedStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
encodedStringBuffer.append("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID=" + URLEncoder.encode(getAdaptivePaymentUserName(), PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE) + "&");
    encodedStringBuffer.append("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD=" + URLEncoder.encode(getAdaptivePaymentPassword(), PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE) + "&");
    if (!isUseCert()) {
        encodedStringBuffer.append("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE=" + URLEncoder.encode(getAdaptivePaymentSignature(), PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE) + "&");
    }
    // encodedStringBuffer.append("BUTTONSOURCE=" +
    // URLEncoder.encode(PayPalConstants.BUTTONSOURCE,
    // PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE) + "&");
    encodedStringBuffer.append("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT=" + URLEncoder.encode("NV", PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE) + "&");
    encodedStringBuffer.append("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=" + URLEncoder.encode("NV", PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE) + "&");
    encodedStringBuffer.append("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID=" + URLEncoder.encode(getAdaptivePaymentAppId(), PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE) + "&");

                final PostMethod httpPost = new PostMethod(this.adaptivePaymentRestURL.getPath());

    httpPost.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(encodedStringBuffer.toString(), "text/html", PayPalConstants.ENCODE_TYPE));
final int result = this.adaptivePaymentHttpClient.executeMethod(httpPost);
                    if (result == 200) {
            response = httpPost.getResponseBodyAsString();
}
```

---

And the response value is comming like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns3:FaultMessage xmlns:ns3="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/common" xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
<responseEnvelope>
<timestamp>2013-08-21T00:20:51.291-07:00</timestamp>
<ack>Failure</ack>
<correlationId>e3325********</correlationId>
<build>694****</build>
</responseEnvelope>
<error>
**<errorId>520003</errorId>**
<domain>PLATFORM</domain>
<subdomain>Application</subdomain>
<severity>Error</severity>
<category>Application</category>
<message>Authentication failed. API credentials are incorrect.</message>
</error>
</ns3:FaultMessage>
```

so can anyone please tell me what I have done wrong?
Is the Input string buffer is the wrong data type for this webservice.
Please help me.. I am totally confused of this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The API Credentials either go as HTTP headers (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/#headers) or https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/#payload. You seem to be mixing up the two - X-PAYPAl-* are HTTP header names.